# Use CartoDB Dark Matter basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, wms, carto

How can I add [Dark Matter](https://carto.com/location-data-services/basemaps/) from carto.com in my QGIS project?

As WMS by example or with a plugin.

Comment: One option is to run an instance of mapproxy.org , which will fetch the tiles and expose a WMS interface that then can be consumed from qgis.

Comment: Didn't know mapproxy. Interesting but the solutionbelow is simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) QGIS plugin.

Search Dark Matter basemap in https://qms.nextgis.com/

I found:

1. https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/529/
2. https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/472/
3. https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/481/
4. https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/482/

[image]

Comment: How can i see the qms repository where the search is done? Because i see nowhere the Dark matter in the plugin

Comment: Make sure you have installed latest plugin version (0.18.5), open search pane (https://snag.gy/KDagQF.jpg) and enter Dark Matter. Then push "Add".

Comment: I see the feature. It works. But the quick finder is looking somewhere and i would like to know where.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the plugin works with http://qms.nextgis.com service via API. You can add your additional favourite basemaps there.